# Power BI Azure Maps Visual dynamic reference layer?

Tags: powerbi, azure-maps

How do I make the reference layer in the PowerBI Azure Maps Visual dynamic?

**Example:**

- Uploaded a `.geojson` file as Reference Layer
- When this data changes, I want the Reference Layer to update and the map to reflect the changes

**Desired state:**

- Ideally, the Reference Layer would be treated as a Data Source and I could make an API call with PowerBI to update

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference layers are based on a single flat file that are uploaded into the visual and does not connect to an external data set similar to the Shape map visual. This is by design and done for security reasons.

Currently the Azure Maps visual has the following options for connecting live data to the map;

- A single Power BI data set connected through the visual field pane. This is currently limited to point data that has latitude and longitude columns. Support for geocoding addresses is planned as well as potentially other shapes (i.e. Polygons).
- The custom tile layer overlay. You can connect to a custom tile layer service. If the data in your tile layer refreshes, set the cache header age to the refresh interval and the tiles will automatically update.

We are looking at other ways to bring in external data in a secure manner, such as the Azure Maps Creator platform.

Comment: @ericOnline If this answer is helpful, please "Accept answer" or "Up-Vote" for the same which might be beneficial to other community members reading this thread.

Comment: @rbundritt are you still active on this question

Comment: @ombk I'm always monitoring the dev community for feedback. If you have a feature request, I recommend submitting it here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/909172-azure-maps